# Save a copy of any attachments included with an incoming SMS via Twilio

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I successfully built a tool that uses Twilio voice and Text. It is used by my company to Send/Recive texts and test phone numbers. Unfortunately the only documentation for doing what I'd like to do is for Laravel (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-download-images-incoming-mms-php-laravel). Then there is a very basic guide to SMS Attachments here (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/media-resource#list), unfortunately it doesnt go into detail.

> $media = $twilio->messages($strSID)->media($strAttachmentSID)->fetch();

, but don't know what to do with the object it returns. I expect something simple like

> $media = $twilio->messages($strSID)->media($strAttachmentSID)->fetch()->save();

**Please help me understand what to do with the returned object.**

I have tried using **move_uploaded_file()** on the uri returned by this object, but It didn't work.

I've tried sending a request using curl to the attachment url, but what it returns is given in the post for the incoming message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you receive a message which has media attached the [incoming webhook request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/sms-webhooks) will have a parameter `NumMedia` which will tell you how many media objects there are. Then, for each of them, there will be `MediaUrlX` (where X is a number), which contains the URL of the media object, and `MediaContentTypeX`, which is the MIME type for the media object.

In the laravel example, the content is downloaded with [this function](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/receive-mms-laravel/blob/621f19e905bf99985536f844ecab83e2a2f39e2e/app/Services/MediaMessageService/MediaMessageService.php):

```php
    public function getMediaContent($mediaUrl)
    {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mediaUrl);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

      // Option to follow the redirects, otherwise it will return an XML
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      $media = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $media;
    }
```

Which you call with the media URL, e.g.

```php
$contents = getMediaContent($_POST["MediaUrl0"]);
```

You would then need to save the contents to a file.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used file_put_contents($strTargetFile, getMediaContent($mediaUrl)) to create the file. Is there a preffered way?

Comment: That seems like it would work to me. I’m not much of a PHP programmer though, so I don’t know if there’s a better way.